NDSolve infinite expression
Here is the differential equation I want to solve
\[Alpha] = 3;
NDSolve[{\[Sigma]rr'[r] == 
   1/r (-\[Sigma]rr[r] + \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][
       r]), \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta]'[r] == 
   1/r (\[Sigma]rr[r] - \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][
        r]) - \[Alpha] r^2  \[Sigma]rr[r]^-2, \[Sigma]rr[
    0] == \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][0], \[Sigma]rr[1] == 
   1}, {\[Sigma]rr, \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta]}, {r, 0, 1}]

It of course outputs infinite expression because of the singularity at r=0. When I face this kind of singularity, I used to either slight shift the integration range to avoid the singularity, or I multiply r for both sides to remove the explicit singularity. My question is neither works for this one, and I wonder how to make it work. I know there is a solution where \[Sigma]rr[0] and \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][0] are about 1.
A detour I can think of is writing two separate NDSolve with respect to \[Sigma]rr[0] and \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][0] and using FindRoot to satisfiy \[Sigma]rr[0]==\[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][0]. This actually works with a lot of error messages including the infinite expression. I belive there should be a much better way to solve it. I would also appreciate if you can give some general advice to deal with the singularity issue when numerically solving differential equations.

You have BC that looks like this R[0]==T[0] where I just renamed your Greek letter to R and T. . Then you have another BC R[1]==1. You have two ode's. How will NDSolve know what is starting value for T[0]?  When I have IC to both R and T at zero, then it works.

@Nasser thanks for the comment. I think that is what I am trying to figure out. R[0]==T[0] and R[1]==1 are the given boundary conditions I have to use. If this is not a good approach, can you suggest a different way to tackle this problem? When I have those types of boundary conditions?

I could only make it work with BC, like in this screen shot. Not what you show.,  https://i.sstatic.net/oe7k6A4i.png  but the condition R[0]==T[0] looks suspicious to me with numerical solver. May be someone else have better idea.

Your first ode has general solution \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][r]=D[r \[Sigma]rr[r] , r]
r \[Sigma]rr'[r] == (-\[Sigma]rr[r] + \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][r]) /. \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta] -> Function[r, D[r \[Sigma]rr[r] , r] ]
\[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][r] /. \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta] ->Function[r, D[r \[Sigma]rr[r], r] ] (* True*)

Substituting in the second ode
oder = r \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta]'[r] ==  (\[Sigma]rr[r] -\[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][r]) - \[Alpha] r^3 \[Sigma]rr[r]^-2 /. \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta] ->Function[r, D[r \[Sigma]rr[r], r] ] // Simplify



eps = 10^-6 (* exclude singularity*)
sigr = NDSolveValue[{ode, \[Sigma]rr[1] == 1,eps Derivative[1][\[Sigma]rr][eps] == 0}, \[Sigma]rr, {r, eps, 1}]
Plot[{sigr[r], Evaluate[ D[r sigr[r], r]]  }, {r, eps, 1},PlotRange -> All]


Hope it helps!
addendum
Using ParametricNDSolve we can solve two odes
First we solve the odes with boundary conditions \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][1] == c1, \[Sigma]rr[1] ==1
\[Alpha] = 3;
eps = 10^-6
sol = ParametricNDSolve [{r \[Sigma]rr'[
      r] == (-\[Sigma]rr[r] + \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][r]), 
   r \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta]'[
      r] ==  (\[Sigma]rr[r] - \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][
        r]) - \[Alpha] r^3 \[Sigma]rr[r]^-2, \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][
     1] == c1, \[Sigma]rr[1] == 
    1}, {\[Sigma]rr, \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta]}, {r, eps, 1}, c1]

Now we try to choose c1 in such a way that \[Sigma]rr[const][0] == \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][const][0] is fullfilled:
J[const_?NumericQ] := (\[Sigma]rr[const][0] - \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][const][0]  )^2 /. sol ;

mini = NMinimize[{1, 0 == J[const], const > 0}, const] // Quiet
Plot[Evaluate[{\[Sigma]rr[const][r], \[Sigma]\[Theta]\[Theta][const][r]} /. sol /. mini[[2]]], {r, 0, 1}]



Yes this help. Thanks a lot!
By the way, I have some follow up questions. The first equation is pretty simple and one may get the general solution by hands and plug it into the second equation like you did. Let's suppose the first equation is much more complicated and the general solution is not very intuitive. Can we find the general solution of it (when we have one equation with two functions of one variable) using Mathematica? or can we still solve this equation numerically without knowing the general solution of the first equation?

@physg See my addendum where I solve your problem with some kind of shootingmethod
